# Is there any disadvantages in losing too much weight in minimum time

Tags: bellyfat

I am 26 years old, height : 6.1 , weight : 78

I look thin, but i have too much belly fat , I guess its all because that i eat white rice 2/3 times in day.

so I want to reduce **belly fat** , so if i **run** daily for an hour and do **cardi**o for an hour,  spending one hour in **gym** and one hour in **yoga** class and if i control my **diet** is it going to affect on my health ?

Comment: Mind you, there is no way to "only" lose belly fat specifically. Your best guess is to build muscle. What apex means is to try and build muscle, which not necessarily means losing weight, but fat, as muscle weighs more than fat.

Comment: I am assuming that you mean 78 kilos which is 171.6 lbs US.

Comment: @skymningen Thanks for nice information.....

Comment: @JohnP that's right.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Losing too much weight quickly can be bad for you health, not going to list all the side effects, so its better to do a controlled weight loss.

By your description its seems like you are skinny fat, and the only way to correct this is to lose weight. I would recommend adding weight training to your routine for a more aesthetic look.